# How to make excel sheet with "comma style" cell in Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

My task is to format excel file to "comma style".
For example I have value 0 or 0.00 in my cell, and I press "," button in excel

[image]

as a result my value becomes "-".

[image]

if I have value "Hello"

[image]

after pressing this button - value moves little bit right:

[image]

My task is to emulate pressing this button in Apache poi, how can I do it?

I have no idea how to do it!
All I could find is formatting below, but it doesn't work:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String s[]) {
    try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream
                ("dateFormat.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = hssfworkbook.createSheet
                ("new sheet");
        HSSFCellStyle cs = hssfworkbook.createCellStyle();
        HSSFDataFormat df = hssfworkbook.
                createDataFormat();
        cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0.0"));
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)0);
        cell.setCellValue(11111.0);
        cell.setCellStyle(cs);

        HSSFCell cell2 = row.createCell((short)1);
        cell2.setCellValue(0);
        cell2.setCellStyle(cs);

        HSSFCell cell3 = row.createCell((short)2);
        cell3.setCellValue("hello");
        cell3.setCellStyle(cs);

        hssfworkbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
}
```

Also I have separate task - if value is 1.0 it should become 1, if you could help me with this formatting would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that code, I had a similar task but parsed the numbers myself... Here's the code, not sure if it's gonna help you though:

```java
private String getNumericValue(final String raw) {
    final double value = Double.parseDouble(raw);
    final String strValue = String.valueOf(new BigDecimal(value).setScale(1, RoundingMode.CEILING).doubleValue()).replace('.', ',');
    if (strValue.endsWith(",0"))
        return strValue.substring(0, (strValue.length() - 2));
    return strValue;
}
```